# Плохо различимый цвет шрифта при входе в замороженную комнату

Tags: дефект, статус-воспроизведено, локализация

[Чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43094/discussion-on-question-by-mihail-ris-----python).

Текст `This room is frozen; new messages cannot be added.` внутри эллипса едва видно:

[image: Замороженная комната]

Проверял в браузерах Firefox 48.0.2 и Chrome 52.0.2743.116 .

Comment: вот про это уже говорили вроде, может даже на мете уже было

Comment: Это на мобильном? У меня нет такой плашки внизу.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, нет, на ПК, Windows 10. Если Вы о синем эллипсе, то это я нарисовал его, чтобы показать, где располагается текст. Больше ничего не пририсовывал. Спасибо.

Comment: @NickVolynkin в мобильном браузере нормальный серый фон